# calling objective c method from c function

Tags: objective-c, c, nstextview

I tried doing this in my objective C method

```
my_function(self);

my_function(void *param)
{

id self = param;
[self.Output insertText:@"Hello world"];

}
```

Output is of type `NSTextView`.

I get the following errors in compilation

```
Use of undeclared identifier 'id' in the line  "id self = param".
```

I tried `#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>`, but didn't help. In the line `[self.Output insertText:@"Hello world"];`, I get `"Expected expression"` error.

Basically, what i am trying to do is to share some data periodically between my c function(where it's generated) and objective c method(where it's processed and displayed). I am total newbie in objective c, any help is greatly appreciated. If there is a better way to do this than calling objective c methods from C function, I am open to that.

Comment: Is this code in a `.m` file or a `.c` file? It needs to be in a `.m` file. And don't name your variable `self`. That is a reserved word.

Comment: @rmaddy `self` is not a reserved word.  Inside a method, it is a variable that is defined for you automatically, but even there you can redeclare it in a nested scope.

Comment: @robmayoff OK. It seems you are right. Personally I would avoid its use since it when I see `self` I assume that it is a reference to the current object instance.

Comment: The "undeclared identifier" error strongly suggests that you're not in a .m or .mm file but in a .c file.  You can freely code C code in a .m file, but not so Objective-C in a .c file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use objektive-c in .c files. But you can use c in .m files so if you need to mix make sure its a .m file.

Comment: thanks, that was issue. Renaming the file to .m fixed the issue.